# Unable to check out tag created via the github API

Tags: python, github, git-branch, github-api, git-tag

I followed the instructions at this [Github create tag](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/#create-a-tag-object) API reference which say to :

```
1) create a tag from a sha
2) create a reference for that commit
```

I did both.  The reference is of course just a branch, and I can check it out in my terminal just fine and view it in Github web just fine.

The tag however is nowhere to be found, not with Github web nor git checkout tags/tag-name

My code is as follows:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/MYORG/MYREPO/git/tags'
params = dict(ref="refs/heads/MyNewTag",    sha="SHA")
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'token'))
# this works and returns a 201 with its own sha
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/MYORG/MYREPO/git/refs', params = dict(ref="refs/heads/MyNewBranch", sha="SHA")
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'token'))
#this also works and returns a 201
```

But as I said, the tag is not in Github web, nor can I check it out locally.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the **ref** that I was creating.  It should be **ref/tags/MYNewTag**.  The code for this is:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

#create a release branch from the desired commit
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/MYORG/MYREPO/git/refs'
params = dict(ref="refs/heads/MyNewBranch", sha="SHA")
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'token'))

#you should check for res.status_code first to avoid erorr
sha = res.json()['object']['sha']
# create a tag from the desired sha (same one that was used to create the release branch)
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/MYORG/MYREPO/git/tags'
params = dict(tag="MyNewTag", message="testing tagging with API", object=sha, type="commit",
       tagger={name=name, email=email, data=date})
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'token'))

#now get the sha of the new tag
sha = res.json()['object']['sha'] # again don't forget check status_code
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/ttcpaselect/cpaselect/git/refs'
params = dict(ref="refs/tags/MyNewTag", sha=sha)
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'token'))
```

Now you can checkout the tag in your local repo after you do a git fetch as so:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout tags/MyNewTag
```